# How do I make a gfy full screen?

Tags: jquery, css, gif

I am having trouble resizing my gfy's.  I would like them to take up 100% of the viewport.  I assume that I'm not selecting the correct class or ID.  I've inspected the element.  I'm just not sure where to go from here.  I have tried making the full screen.  I think my problem is that I'm not selecting the correct class from their stylesheet, but I'm at a loss.  I appreciate any help.

```
<body>   
    <div class="gfy" data-key="65">
        <img class="gfyitem" data-id="SafeSevereAustralianfreshwatercrocodile" data-controls="false" data-dot="false" data-perimeter="true" data-expand="true">
    </div>         
</body>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.gfy { 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    background-position: center center; 
    background-color: black; 
    background-size: cover; 
    display: none;
}

.gfyitem {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
 }
```

Comment: try setting html & body height to 100%. If the only element inside body is fixed there is nothing to give body any height

Comment: Thanks, @charlietfl.  My body and html are set to 100%.  I wonder if there is a hard-coded (is that the right term? maybe I mean inline-styling) CSS within the gfy that I need to change.

Comment: @j08691    [gfycat](http://gfycat.com/) Basically, it's silent and loads faster that a gif.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone!

```
<div class="gfy" data-key="90">
  <img class="gfyitem" data-id="VibrantAncientAmericanbulldog" data-controls="false" data-dot="false" data-perimeter="true" data-expand="true" data-filetype="image">
</div>


$(window).on('keydown', function(e) {
  $('[data-key="' + e.which + '"]').show();
  $('#letter-key').html(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)).show();
});
```